# Popup with functional close button (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, pug

I'm a total rookie, but I'm trying to make a website and I bumped into an issue, unfortunately.

I have a set of articles (cards) in a grid. Each card contains a "thumbnail" with the title, an image and a short preview of the text. The idea is that when you click the card item, a pop up will appear with the full article that may including varying HTML and CSS. Once clicked, the background also gets blurry.
The pop up will have a close button in the top right corner.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the full article is a child of the card item. This means that the click function keeps happening when inside the article. So even when I click the close button, it is immediately reopened. I want users to be able to click and interact with the article without accidently closing it, unless they clicked on the `.close` div.

Allow me to share the code (it is written in pug/jade):

HTML(Pug):

```
.card(onclick="expandFunction()")
    .image
    .information
        h4.title Preview Title
        p.description Preview Description
    #blurry.hideme
    article#full.hideme
        h4.m-title Main Title
        p.m-description Main Description 
        p.m-body Main Article
        .close(onclick="contractFunction()")
```

Javascript:

```
function expandFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("full");
  var x = document.getElementById("blurry");
  y.classList.toggle("hideme");
  x.classList.toggle("hideme");
}

function contractFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("full");
  var x = document.getElementById("blurry");
  y.classList.toggle("hideme");
  x.classList.toggle("hideme");
}
```

The `hideme` class is merely a `display: none` that is applied to the divs.

Furthermore, right now my javascript is hardcoded to open one of the card articles using an ID. Is it instead possible to use the relative path so I don't have to create a unique function for each card I have?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but you should consider using a `button` instead of a `div` for the close button. It's better for accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you just have to prevent the click event from propagate through the DOM, i will change your script like this:

```
function expandFunction(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var y = document.getElementById("full");
   var x = document.getElementById("blurry");
   element.classList.toggle("hideme");
   x.classList.toggle("hideme");
}

function contractFunction(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var y = document.getElementById("full");
   var x = document.getElementById("blurry");
   element.classList.toggle("hideme");
   x.classList.toggle("hideme");
}
```

In this way any click you do will affect just the element that fire it and will not travel along the DOM firing other event

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the popup is already opened, if yes don't run the expand function again.

```
function expandFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("blurry");
  if(x.classList.contains("hideme")) { 
    var y = document.getElementById("full");
    element.classList.toggle("hideme");
    x.classList.toggle("hideme");
  }
}
```

This way the only way to close a card would be from `.close` button.